# How To get currently logged in Active directory user name in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to get currently logged in active directory user name/details.

Here, User does log in to machine with its AD username and password. How can i get this user name and other details in Global.asax file  for Application_AuthenticateRequest() Event.

I have used 
`System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`
But, when it hosted on IIS 6.0 returns Server's users credentials. such as "domain\username". I have currently enabled Anonymous Access and Integrated Authentication. And in project using Form Authentication.

Should I use System.Directory.dll

Answer (score 2):

If you want the windows credentials, then you should disable anonymous access, and use windows security instead of forms authentication in your application.

You use [HttpContext.User.Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx) to get the name of the logged in user inside your application. If you use forms auth, then you will get the name of the logged in forms-user, if you use integrated security and windows auth, then you get the AD name of the user.

Comment: One More Thing, I am using personalization setting in my application, I have changed it as you told but it gives error "Personalization not enabled" and when I change it to Form Authentication in Application, it works but again restores IIS user name provided that Anonymous is Enabled. If I disable it It ask for user name and password for accessing application that i don't want. please reply.

Comment: To be clear, you want a user database with user profiles, but based on AD credentials, right?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have DB for user profiles and I want AD credentials (username),  he/she entered when loged into system. Any Solution?...

Comment: Check this old blog post by ScottGu - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx